# I want to show that $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2\mu [e^t(t-1)+1]}{t^2\left [(1-2\mu)+2\mu\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right]}=\mu$

Tags: limits

I would like to show this limit:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2\mu [e^t(t-1)+1]}{t^2\left [(1-2\mu)+2\mu\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right]}=\mu$$

for $\mu \leq 1/2$.

Comment: Does not [L'Hopital''s rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) work for this?

Comment: @hypernova is it possible without L'Hopital?

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is only a particular case of order $1$ Taylor expansion, you can directly compute the expansion here.

Comment: @Melina: You may use Taylor expansion for $e^t$ for its first several terms instead. Target is to cancel also the unfriendly $t$'s that appear as a denominator in each fraction. But the mechanism behind is the same with L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @hypernova Except that L'H will be immensely more painful (not to mention its hypothesis, which are almost never checked). All in all, a strange suggestion to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $t$ goes to $0$ you have:
$$e^t(t-1)+1=\left(1+t+t^2/2+O(t^3) \right)(t-1)+1=\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^3)$$
$$\frac{e^t-1}{t}=\frac{1+t+O(t^2)-1}{t}=1+O(t)$$
so:

$$\frac{e^t(1-t)+1}{t^2\left(1-2\mu+2\mu \frac{e^t-1}{t}\right)}=\frac{t^2/2+O(t^3)}{t^2\left(1-2\mu+2\mu+O(t)\right)} \sim \frac{1}{2}$$

Multiplying by $2 \mu$ you obtain the result.

Comment: In the final line, you have a $O(t^2)$ term in the numerator - how can you neglect this?

Comment: I have made a mistake thank you :-)

Comment: @Delta-u I think you missed -1 in second line step 2.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the multiple mistakes ^^

Answer (score 2):

Taking a Taylor series expansion,

$$\begin{align}&\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2\mu [e^t(t-1)+1]}{t^2\left [(1-2\mu)+2\mu\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right]}\\
=&\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2\mu \left[(1+t+\frac{1}{2}t^2 + O(t^3))(t-1)+1\right]}{t^2\left [(1-2\mu)+2\mu(1 +  O(t))\right]} \\
=&\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2\mu \left[-1+\frac{1}{2}t^2 +1+O(t^3)\right]}{t^2\left [1+ O(t))\right]} \\
=&\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\mu t^2+O(t^3)}{t^2 + O(t^3)}=\mu.\end{align}$$